# Can I Ask About Networking Specifications Related To a Database Setup?

Tags: discussion

**Background**

In a datacenter rack I want to dedicate 10Us for DB that an app connects to directly and another 10 for backup purposes. For security purposes, the IP addresses for those backup servers are all local (e.g., 10.10.10.[1-10]); however have a question about the number of static IP addresses I require for the direct accessed DBs.

Can I ask about the networking specifications for this purpose on the 'Database Administrators' site?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing all the details of the question you propose asking, but I would say that there would have to be a fairly strong element of **database-specific** configuration for this to be on-topic here. To put it another way, it needs to be reasonably likely to be answerable here, and to require some knowledge specific to database professionals.

For example, questions about configuring a network to work well with database clustering technologies would likely be on-topic; general questions about configuring a corporate network that just *happens* to serve a database would probably be better suited to **[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)**. Or, for a non-business environment, **[Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)**.

If you are confident your question is **specific enough** to Database Administration, by all means go ahead and ask it on the main site, after reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help).

Should it later become apparent that the question would be better on Server Fault or Super User, you can always flag it for a moderator to migrate (assuming it is on-topic at the destination).

---

[Aaron Bertrand:](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) Just to further clarify the last point, if you post the question and someone suggests it is better suited for a different site, please **flag and wait for migration**, rather than adding an identical question on the other site. Migration is much easier for the sites to deal with than identical duplicates.